# Storing output of a bash command to database

Tags: mysql, awk, iptables, usage-statistics

I want to store the output of `iptables -vL` command into a mysql database table. When I run `iptables -vL` it shows usage in bytes along with users MAC id's. I am planning to use awk to select two columns (usage "$2" and MAC id's "$6") from the output of the above command. And those two clomuns should go to the database. The usage column in the database should add up whenever the tables are updated.

Comment: Have you tried writing to a file with the appropriate INSERT statements and then executing that SQL file?  Would that do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing the iptables output with awk, format it out as Mysql INSERT statements, and then pipe the results into the mysql command line.  Something like:

```
iptables -vL | awk {your awk commands here} | mysql --user=foo --password=bar yourdatabasename
```